# Retrofit waits for timeout response

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, coroutine

I have 4 tab(fragments) which in its viewmodel launch coroutine for calling related apis and when i switch the tabs coroutine will cancel and works perfectly even when one request gets socketTimedOut exception ... problem starts when server is under pressure and one api gets socketTimeOut and suddenly even though coroutine got canceled but retrofit ignores coroutine cancellation and waits for the response of api that got timedOut and fires all the cancelled previous requests ... it seems like retrofit creates a queue or something !... does anyone have any idea...

Comment: Seeing the actual code would help us a lot

Comment: Are any of your viewmodels extending AndroidViewModel?

Comment: viewmodel:

    val viewStateShop = MutableLiveData<Resource<ShopResultDto>>()


val scope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())    

 val viewStateShop = MutableLiveData<Resource<ShopResultDto>>()

fun getShopList(requestDto: RequestDto) {
        scope.launch (Dispatchers.IO+coroutineExceptionHandler) {
            viewStateShop.postValue( shopRepository.getShopListTest(requestDto))
        }
    }

Comment: repository:

 suspend fun  getShopList(requestDto: RequestDto): Resource<ShopResultDto> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO+coroutineExceptionHandler){
            shopService.getShops(requestDto)
        }
    }